# SWRevealViewController hides tab bar controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SWRevealViewController and tab bar view controller. A table view is hooked to the back of the tab bar. If I select any of the cells,the view transitions to the correct view but my tab bar buttons disappear. This is the hierarchy of the views:

SWRevealViewController - > SideTableViewController - > tab bar controller >tab 1

Not sure what is going on. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: I think issue is because of view hierarchy. I don't know why you have added tabBarController in tableViewController, but the way should be like tabBarController is your rootViewController and `SWRevealViewController - > SideTableViewController` is independent to tabBarController (try to add it as a subview with animation).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when using `SWRevealViewController`. What I believe is happening is that you are linking to one of the individual `TabBar Views`, instead of linking it to the `TabBarViewController`. But, without a picture of your storyboard, I can't be 100% sure